# Need help for SQL query to generate result like google map address textbox

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to replicate maps.google.com address textbox. So I have used in my code texbox autocomplete event. I wrote one query that is not exactly working.

Here is query:

> I am using two wild card because if I type addressno or streetname it
>   should work for both. but here i have problem with addresnumber if I
>   type 12 it should bring only those address which start from 12 not
>   6123.

Query:

```
select top 10 GEOADDRESS 
from Address_Points 
where " & "GEOADDRESS like '%' + @SearchText + '%'
```

This query returns all kinds of values for example if I start typing addressnumber 12. it will return this result

```
6123 xyz st,
7812 ggg st
```

I need exact result like google map address bar.

If I start typing 12 it should bring only 1234 xyz blv or 1278 pqr blv. and If I type xyz blv still it should work.

Please help me to write the query so I can get exact result like google address textbox.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you want to look for a precise result for character data, you can use the CONTAINS and FREETEXT predicates in SQL Server. You can find some examples in the MSDN [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142583.aspx).

The [Full-Text search](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) is an optional feature, that you can install in SQL Server.
Make sure you have it installed in your instance before using the aforementioned operators, using this code:

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('IsFullTextInstalled')
```

The query will return `1` if the feature is installed, `0` or `NULL` otherwise.